# Design panel using percentage in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

While designing winforms in C#, panel is generically specified in Width/Height. Is there any way to implement the same via percentage so that when another hidden panel becomes visible the size of the existing panels does not get affected.

I tried to set the location and size in the back end once the hidden panel becomes visible which makes the design looks like a bug.

Comment: How is *the size of the existing panels* compromised when another control becomes visible? Do you mean the *relative* size? Are you resizing your controls dinamically, somehow? If this is the case, have you tested a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview) (its cells can be sizes proportionally)?

Comment: Tried the same one but no luck.The requirement would be like. We do have one parent panel with many child panels, and one slidemenu at the left. Once we hit slidemenu button the hidden panel get expanded where the child panel size and locations get affected. Is there any permanent fix so that the design becomes more user friendly ??

Comment: Yes. Use a TabControl. You can hide the TabControl's labels at run-time (so just the first TabPage is visible) and you switch to another TabPage when a Button is clicked. But, at design-time, the TabControls labels are visible and you can switch from a TabPage to another even in the Form's Designer (making it much easier to handle mulltiple Panels and child controls). If I've understood your layout correctly, I mean.

Comment: Perhaps you want to have one parent Panel, and each child docked Top in the parent. Then, on button click(s), hide or show the child Panels? Without a well written requirement to go on, it's just a guess.

Comment: When the parent panel becomes visible the size of child panels gets affected and auto scroll is getting enabled. Which is not the requirement.